# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_equeue_script addjs wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(288): addjs('') #1

Tags: javascript

I have written a addjs function listed below. and I get fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_equeue_script()

```
function addjs()
{

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');


    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/css3-mediaqueries.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/superfish.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tms-0.4.1.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jssor.slider-27.1.0.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jassorsid.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 'custom.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
    wp_equeue_script('jquery');

}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `enqueue` - you're missing an n

Note also that everywhere you write `'jquery'` you're supposed to use unique identifiers. And if you're enqueuing it directly after registering you can change the name of all register functions directly to enqueue and then remove the line below.

Comment: Hi marks, thanks for the reply,  i renamed every jquery as below - wp_register_script('jquery1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
 wp_equeue_script('jquery1');

    
    wp_register_script('jquery2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/css3-mediaqueries.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
 wp_equeue_script('jquery2');
 
    wp_register_script('jquery3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js', array(), 1, 1, 1);
 wp_equeue_script('jquery3');
 still i get the same error

Comment: Thanks marks i had miss spelled now i am getting a new error -> GET http://localhost/andyslandscapingjs/slider.js?ver=5.3.2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Please help me i am trying different method